# Как выровнять блок по центру экрана

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка

есть у меня вот такой тег `div`:

```
<div id="game"></div>
```

Скажите, как его выровнять по центру экрана?
CSS приветствуется.

Comment: в поиске не пробовали забить, прямо так заголовок?

Comment: это конечно глупо, но...
margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Куча статей на эту тему с тоннами информации, вот например https://habr.com/post/238449/

Comment: А вы хотя бы пытались искать ответ на ваш вопрос?! 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Вот тут блок =)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!

Comment: Можете принять ответ, если он решает ваш вопрос.